# Conditional objects in access report?

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

I have a table with 2 different sets of customers form 2 different company, marked by an A or B in the company column. I am creating a report for invoices, i need to change the company name and details depending on it being company a or company b. Is this even possible. If not does anyone know of a good solution, or another option.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need a table called tblCompany, with an Identifier column (A, B, etc...) and all other info like Name, Address, etc...  Then you would make a query that joins your first table to tblCompany, on the Identifier column.  Your report would be based off that query, where you could pull in the Name from tblCompany, and all the other info from the first table.

Unless there's something I'm not understanding?

Comment: No.. that sounds like a good way do do it. let me work with this and see what i can do! THANKS

Comment: @user2162192 - If this solution works, please come back and consider giving my answer a checkmark.  It will help me become a trusted member of the community.  If you have any questions, post them here and use the "@" sign as I have done, which will let me know that a response was made here.  Good luck!